# Masking an ImageView onto Another ImageView

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, mask

I'm trying to load a record or a cd mask onto an image view which contains the Album Cover of the currently playing song from the MediaPlayer.framework. The record looks like this 'http://cl.ly/4w1h' and the image view holding the Image View in the iPhone app has the album cover is a square. Now This is something similar to what I am trying to do:

I take the CD (http://cl.ly/4wdC) or the Record (http://cl.ly/4w1h) and I get something like this on the iPhone [CD:(http://cl.ly/4wYB) | Record:(http://cl.ly/4wQI)]. The layers from photoshop look like this with masks. http://cl.ly/4vu4. So taking the masks and using them on the iPhone to overlay on top of the UIImageView. Is this even possible? If you have questions about my wording, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in a viewController:

```
    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,220)];// or whatever size you want
[self.view addSubview:v];
UIImageView *iv_1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FirstImage.png"]];
UIImageView *iv_2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CD_Image.png"]];
iv_2.alpha = .5;   // play with this number between 0 (transparent) and 1.0 (opaque).
[v addSubview:iv_1];
[v addSubview:iv_2];
    [iv_1 release];
    [iv_2 release];
    [v release];
```

Comment: Well, what I meant was you idea did work but the album cover wasn't masked in the shape of the CD. Just had the CD's opacity overlayed on it.

Comment: @Frank - ok, now I think I understand your question.  You want the underlying album cover to show through a CD or Record -shaped hole, right?  So make the CD or Record masks in PhotoShop: black edges with transparency inside the circle.  Then do the code I gave you, but omit the "alpha" line.